# Jsp Page shows some unwanted Character in browser?

Tags: html, jsp, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I have some problem while using Custom Portlet In My liferay Don't know but some how when I deploy my war file to other machines liferay server it shows me one page with some unwanted character while there is no character in my jsp page. but there is no error of javascript or html tag used in jsp page.

here is the image of jsp page.

[image]

My Code Of jsp page is as follows

```
<%@ include file="/init.jsp"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.util.portlet.PortletProps"%>
<%@page import="emenu.advertise.emailnotification.EmailNotification"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.model.Role"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.model.Organization"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil"%>
<%@page import="emenu.advertise.portlet.RestaurantPortlet"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.util.portlet.PortletProps"%>;
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletConfig"%>
<%@ page import="com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine"%>
<portlet:renderURL var="editadvertiseURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jsps/advertise/EditAdvertise.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<portlet:renderURL var="addAdvertiseURL">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jsps/advertise/NewAdvertise.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<portlet:renderURL var="advertiselistUrl">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/jsps/advertise/AdvertiseList.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<%
if(!themeDisplay.isSignedIn())
                                                              {
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location="<%=themeDisplay.getURLSignIn()%>";
</script>
<%} %>

<%
    String loading_img_path = request.getContextPath()
            + "/img/ajax_loader.gif";
%>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/lib/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/lib/datatables/jquery.dataTables.sorting.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/gebo_tables.js"></script>
<%  String sRoleName=null;
boolean isReseller= Common.CheckisReseller(themeDisplay);
if(isReseller){
    sRoleName="Reseller";
}
else{   
    sRoleName="Advertiser";
}   %>

<nav>
    <div id="jCrumbs" class="breadCrumb module">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><%=sRoleName%></a></li>
            <li>Ads</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Now Problem Comes Somewhere exactly before the tag of

```
<nav>
        <div id="jCrumbs" class="breadCrumb module">
```

let me give u image of the mozila firebug 
[image]

In My Machine Server it's worked perfectly. but don't know what happens when I try to export war or even try to deploy with eclipse..it's showing this unwanted character in my jsp page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.util.portlet.PortletProps"%>;
```

with

```
<%@page import="com.liferay.util.portlet.PortletProps"%>
```

Comment: oh man..how these doesnt noticed me...its really small mistake..i have wasted hours...thanx..

Comment: you're welcome :) I had a similar issue recently with a extra'>' char in the imports